# Unhandled exception rendering component: System.Net.NameResolution is not supported on this platform error with ldap blazor login page

Tags: c#, razor, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am working on a login page that uses Ldap to authenticate AD information when the login button is clicked and is successful it redirects to the /surplus page. however when I click the login button I get this error:

```
blazor.webassembly.js:1 crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: System.Net.NameResolution is not supported on this platform.
System.PlatformNotSupportedException: System.Net.NameResolution is not supported on this platform.
   at System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddressesAsync(String hostNameOrAddress)
   at Novell.Directory.Ldap.Connection.Connect(String host, Int32 port, Int32 semaphoreId)
   at Novell.Directory.Ldap.Connection.Connect(String host, Int32 port)
   at Novell.Directory.Ldap.LdapConnection.Connect(String host, Int32 port)
   at RazorCPSSurplus.Client.Classes.AuthenticationService.Authenticate(String username, String password) in D:\cdebrodie\Documents\Repos\RazorSurplus\RazorCPSSurplus\Client\Classes\AuthenticationService.cs:line 30
   at RazorCPSSurplus.Client.Pages.LoginPage.Login() in D:\cdebrodie\Documents\Repos\RazorSurplus\RazorCPSSurplus\Client\Pages\LoginPage.razor:line 34
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState)
u @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
Ke._internal.dotNetCriticalError @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
_bound_js_Blazor__internal_dotNetCriticalError @ _bound_js_Blazor__internal_dotNetCriticalError:7
Ss @ dotnet.7.0.10.pc0ureugfn.js:5
_mono_wasm_invoke_bound_function @ dotnet.7.0.10.pc0ureugfn.js:14
$func313 @ 009931b2:0x1d5eb
$func283 @ 009931b2:0x1cae4
$func221 @ 009931b2:0xe1d4
$func220 @ 009931b2:0xd044
$func8115 @ 009931b2:0x1a2377
$func2040 @ 009931b2:0x85b46
$func2038 @ 009931b2:0x85abc
$func1395 @ 009931b2:0x6889a
$func313 @ 009931b2:0x1d66f
$func283 @ 009931b2:0x1cae4
$func221 @ 009931b2:0xe1d4
$func220 @ 009931b2:0xd044
$func8115 @ 009931b2:0x1a2377
$func2040 @ 009931b2:0x85b46
$func2045 @ 009931b2:0x861ae
$func2072 @ 009931b2:0x8826d
$mono_wasm_invoke_method_ref @ 009931b2:0x9d80
Module._mono_wasm_invoke_method_ref @ dotnet.7.0.10.pc0ureugfn.js:14
_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Components_WebAssembly__Microsoft_AspNetCore_Components_WebAssembly_Services_DefaultWebAssemblyJSRuntime_BeginInvokeDotNet @ _Microsoft_AspNetCore_Components_WebAssembly__Microsoft_AspNetCore_Components_WebAssembly_Services_DefaultWebAssemblyJSRuntime_BeginInvokeDotNet:29
beginInvokeDotNetFromJS @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
b @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
invokeMethodAsync @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
invokeWhenHeapUnlocked @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
S @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
A @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
dispatchGlobalEventToAllElements @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
onGlobalEvent @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
```

here is the loginpage.razor code:

```
@page "/login"
@inject RazorCPSSurplus.Client.Classes.AuthenticationService authService
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

<h1>Login</h1>

@if (loginFailed)
{
    <p class="text-danger">Login failed. Please try again.</p>
}

<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" @bind="username">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" @bind="password">
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="Login">Login</button>
</form>

@code {
    private string username;
    private string password;
    private bool loginFailed = false;

    private async Task Login()
    {
        loginFailed = false;

        // Perform LDAP authentication
        if (await authService.Authenticate(username, password))
        {
            // Redirect to the surplus page on successful login
            NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/surplus");
        }
        else
        {
            loginFailed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the AuthenticationService class it uses (took out the server url and domain information for security reasons):

```
using Novell.Directory.Ldap;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RazorCPSSurplus.Client.Classes
{
    public class AuthenticationService
    {
        private readonly LdapConnection _ldapConnection;
        private readonly string _ldapServer;
        private readonly int _ldapPort;
        private readonly string _ldapDomain;

        public AuthenticationService()
        {
            _ldapServer = "ldapurl goes here"; // Replace with your LDAP server address
            _ldapPort = 636; // Replace with your LDAP server port
            _ldapDomain = "columbia"; // Replace with your LDAP domain

            _ldapConnection = new LdapConnection
            {
                SecureSocketLayer = false,
            };
        }

        public async Task<bool> Authenticate(string username, string password)
        {
            try
            {
                _ldapConnection.Connect(_ldapServer, _ldapPort);
                _ldapConnection.Bind($"cn={username},{_ldapDomain}", password);

                return true; // Authentication successful
            }
            catch (LdapException)
            {
                return false; // Authentication failed
            }
            finally
            {
                _ldapConnection.Disconnect();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

any help would be amazing!!!!!